# Are Firefox addons a security risk and if so, how can I block Firefox addons for certain websites?

Tags: firefox, security, firefox-extensions

For example I don’t want any addons being active when I do online banking. Is there an option in Firefox or an addon which allows for deactivating addons for a list of websites?

Comment: I would create a secondary Firefox profile, launch a secondary window in private mode, using a shortcut in order to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It depends largely on the add-on. Fully reviewed add-ons from the official [Mozilla Add-on Site](https://addons.mozilla.org) have been tested for security leaks like this. While it is possible one has been missed, it is unlikely, especially for the most popular add-ons.

Preliminarily reviewed add-ons are more dangerous. The very basics have been checked by a computer, but it's possible some less secure code has snuck in. You should judge those by how much you trust the person who made them.

Add-ons that are found only on other websites are the least secure, and probably should not be used at all unless they come from highly reputable sources.

To increase security, you can use Private Browser Mode, which does disable some add-ons. And, of course, if you are really worried, you can create a new profile as Ramhound suggests, and use Private browsing mode on it.

To do so, create another shortcut to firefox on you desktop, and edit is so that "-no remote -p" comes after the name. (e.g. `"C:\Program Files\firefox.exe" -no-remote -p"` Then open that version, and create a new profile, following the directions as given. From then on, you can select that profile.

If you want, edit the shortcut to add the name of the profile at the end of the shortcut. Use quotes if the name includes spaces, e.g. `"C:\Program Files\firefox.exe" -no-profile -p "High Security"`)